# Is there a way to determine which aws services are being used by a user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-serverless

I need to update our service access policy for an account (IAM user) that has access to a dozen or so services, problem is, I'm not sure which services the account uses.
It's an account that is used by a lot of our services, and developers so it would be unfeasible to track all usages...

I tried getting events from CloudTrail's Event history, but it doesn't give me a full list (i.e can't see any calls to SQS queues made by said account).

So my question is: Is there a way to track all the services that are used with a specific API key that belongs to an IAM user?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_access-advisor.html)?

Comment: You need to **talk** to that user and ask what they need / require. Restricting their permissions without talking to them will certainly cause problems.

Comment: @jellycsc Thanks! Exactly what I needed, can get all relevant info by refining permissions.

Comment: @luk2302 It's a Programmatic access user that is used by a bunch of resources, I needed to determine what it really needs.

Comment: Then you need to ask all the teams / users that maintain the resources using that user to provide you with a list of things they need the user to be able to do. There really is no other way - maybe one using service is currently offline or only runs on the first of every month etc. meaning a naive look at the current usage is not even enough

Answer (score 1):

CloudTrail is a comprehensive list of all API calls invoked by a user. If you don't see SQS calls in CloudTrail then i suggest you double check that the user is making SQS calls or whether they have setup something to hide their SQS calls because CloudTrail is enabled by default and will catch SQS calls.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-logging-using-cloudtrail.html

Comment: Look at the list of "Amazon SQS supports logging the following actions" on the page you linked. Then look at all the available actions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html). Notice how some important actions like `ReceiveMessage` are missing from the CloudTrail list?

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for the reference, that would explain why I couldn't see any of those calls.

Answer (score 0):

As @jellycsc suggested, I can find all the information I needed by going through [Refining permissions in AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_access-advisor.html).

Thanks, everyone!